# How can you programmatically inspect the stack trace of an exception in Python?

Tags: python, exception, stack-trace, traceback

When an exception occurs in Python, can you inspect the stack?  Can you determine its depth?  I've looked at the [traceback](http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html) module, but I can't figure out how to use it.

My goal is to catch any exceptions that occur during the parsing of an eval expression, without catching exceptions thrown by any functions it may have called.  Don't berate me for using eval.  It wasn't my decision.

NOTE: I want to do this programmatically, not interactively.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [inspect](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#the-interpreter-stack) module which has some utility functions for tracing. Have a look at the [overview of properties](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#types-and-members) of the frame objects.

Answer (score 14):

`traceback` is enough - and I suppose that documentation describes it rather well. Simplified example:

```
import sys
import traceback

try:
    eval('a')
except NameError:
    traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)
```

Comment: I'm not trying to print the traceback.  I'm trying to inspect it.  How does this tell me whether the exception occurred in the eval text itself, or in a function called by the evaluated text?

Comment: Many different kinds of errors can be thrown if the eval text is wrong.  I ended up using inspect and looking at the depth of the traceback to see if the error was caused by evaluating the original text, or if it was in the body of a called function.

Answer (score 5):

I like the traceback module.

You can get a traceback object using `sys.exc_info()`.  Then you can use that object to get a list preprocessed list of traceback entries using `traceback.extract_tb()`.  Then you can get a readable list using `traceback.format_list()` as follows:

```
import sys
import traceback, inspect

try:
    f = open("nonExistant file",'r')
except:
    (exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback) = sys.exc_info()
    #print exception type
    print exc_type
    tb_list = traceback.extract_tb(sys.exc_info()[2])
    tb_list = traceback.format_list(tb_list)
    for elt in tb_list:
        print elt
        #Do any processing you need here.
```

See the sys Module: http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html

and the traceback Module: http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html

Answer (score 2):

You define such a function ([doc here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html)):

```
def raiseErr():
   for f in inspect.stack(): print '-', inspect.getframeinfo(f[0])
```

and call it from your modules so:

```
raiseErr()
```

The function *raiseErr* will print info about the place you called it.

More elaborate, you can do so:

```
import inspect, traceback
A = [inspect.getframeinfo(f[0]) for f in inspect.stack()]
print "traceback structure fields:", filter(lambda s: s[0] != '_', dir(A[0]))
print A[0].filename, A[0].lineno
for f in inspect.stack():
    F = inspect.getframeinfo(f[0])
    print '-', F.filename, F.lineno, '\t', F.code_context[0].strip()
```

Other possibility is to define this function:

```
def tr():
    print '* - '*10,
    print sys._getframe(1).f_code.co_name
```

And call it in the place where you want the trace. If you want all the trace, make an iterator from 1 up in `_getframe(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to AndiDog's answer about `inspect`, note that `pdb` lets you navigate up and down the stack, inspecting locals and such things.  The source in the standard library `pdb.py` could be helpful to you in learning how to do such things.