# How do I get the stack trace from an Exception Object in Python?

Tags: python, exception, stack-trace

How can I get the full stack trace from the Exception object itself?

Consider the following code as reduced example of the problem:

```
last_exception = None
try:
    raise Exception('foo failed')
except Exception as e:
    last_exception = e
# this happens somewhere else, decoupled from the original raise
print_exception_stack_trace(last_exception)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can you inspect the stack trace of an exception in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359248/how-can-you-inspect-the-stack-trace-of-an-exception-in-python)

Comment: Well, yes, but that question isn't (satisfactorily) answered!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: I lied, sorry. `e.__traceback__`  is what you want.

```
try:
    raise ValueError
except ValueError as e:
    print( e.__traceback__ )

>c:/python31/pythonw -u "test.py"
<traceback object at 0x00C964B8>
>Exit code: 0
```

This is [only valid](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3134/) in Python 3; you can't do it in earlier versions.

Comment: this is not from the exception object itself but from within the execution trace the exception is thrown in.

Comment: No, in Python 3 it apparently does... I just tried this and it works!

Comment: @katrielalex, how would I do this in Python 2.7, I cant seem to find it.  THanks.

Comment: @Kamilski: to the best of my knowledge you can't get it directly from the exception object; you have to use the `traceback` and/or `inspect` modules.