# Traced Exceptions?

Tags: python, exception

I was wondering if there already existed an exception type that maintains some sort of reference to the point where it was raised. Not even necessarily a full stack trace but maybe just a reference to the method that it was called in. This seems pretty generic so I feel like someone must've created it at some point.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361853/how-do-i-get-the-stack-trace-from-an-exception-object-in-python

Comment: All exceptions have a reference to the stacktrace in Python.