# How to print the __str__ representation of the entire traceback

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, error-handling, raise

When printing an exception using, for instance, `print(ex)`, only the last exception in the chain is printed, how can I instead print all the exceptions in the chain without crowding it with excessive traceback information.

For example:

```
 def test_with_context(context: str, test: int)   
    try:
        assert isinstance(test, int)
        assert test > 4, "Test must be greater than 4"
        assert test < 6, "Test must be smaller than 6"
    exccept AssertionError as ex:
        raise ValueError(f"Invalid test for context {context}") from ex

try: 
    test_with_context("ExampleContext", 8)
except ValueError as ex:
    print("Value Test Failed":)
    print(ex)
```

Provides me with an output of

```
Value Test Failed
ValueError: Invalid test for context ExampleContext
```

Which is useful in providing with me with the overall context, but doesnt tell me what error exactly caused that ValueError.

What I would like to achieve is:

```
Value Test Failed
ValueError: Invalid test for context ExampleContext
AssertionError: Test must be smaller than 6
```

I can use:

```
traceback.print_exc()
```

But that provides me with the entire formatted traceback, line numbers and all, which is too much information to provide a user with a simple input error for instance.

---

Similarly, I have tried using

```
exccept AssertionError as ex:
        ex.add_note(f"Invalid test for context {context}")
```

But it would appear the notes dont appear at all in anything but the full context.

Is there any way to get a nice list of the exception history to print in order?

Comment: Can you just parse out / extract the info you need from `traceback.print_exc()`?

Comment: Does [How can you programmatically inspect the stack trace of an exception in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359248/how-can-you-programmatically-inspect-the-stack-trace-of-an-exception-in-python) answer your question?

Comment: Did you explore any of the other Traceback methods/objects? Nice [examples in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html?highlight=traceback#traceback-examples) showing custom print formats  - did you explore that and try to adapt?

Comment: None of these seem to mention or present solutions for handling the `raise Exception from Exception` syntax. 

I'm not after the full traceback, I dont need to know exactly where each error occurs, I'm just trying to use the exceptions to provide information to the user as to why their input failed - two exception handlers may be several stack layers apart from each other, and the full trace ends up being a nightmare to visually parse.

In terms of manually parsing out the info from traceback.print_exc(), that seems likely to produce a very fragile and context-dependent solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have produced a solution I'm not super keen on, but it does the job:

```
def cause_stack(exception: BaseException) -> List[BaseException]:
    if exception.__cause__ is None:
        return [exception]
    else:
        return [exception] + cause_stack(exception.__cause__)


def format_causes(exception: BaseException) -> str:
    return "\n - caused by -\n".join([str(cause) for cause in cause_stack(exception)])
```

Because the cause of each exception is stored under the `.__cause__` dunder property, recursively searching that can get you a list of each cause in order, which I then format by joining them together with a "caused by" string.

Not super happy with it as a solution - doesn't feel very pythonic, uses recursion which may be problematic with larger stacks and it's not as elegant as one might hope, but it serves my needs for now.